# UIActivityViewController share image and text prevents Instagram activity

Tags: ios, instagram, sharing, uiactivityviewcontroller

The following code brings up the activity view controller for an app that can share both images and text. Instagram only shows up if I remove the `shareText` item.

```
UIImage *shareImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.jpg"];
NSString *shareText = @"some text";
UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[shareImage,shareText] applicationActivities:nil];
```

I would like to be able to share to all services and just drop text if a specific service doesn't support it. I therefore implemented a `UIActivityItemSource` and attempted to filter based on activityType passed in to:

```
- (NSString *)activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController dataTypeIdentifierForActivityType:(nullable UIActivityType)activityType
```

But `activityType` is almost always `nil`. So I can't filter on it.

Anyone have a solution?

Comment: Can you check the more option in the activity controller that is presented . It might be there in the list.

Comment: When I only had the shareImage object shared, yes, that's how I initially enabled it and it worked. But when I share both image and text, then Instagram is not happy and doesn't show up, even under more. It's an odd problem!

Comment: I've even written my own UIActivity that talks to Instagram app but I would like to transition to using the official UIActivity that the actual Instagram app provides. (This custom UIActivity subclass remains the fallback)